# Zend form setAction submits to wrong url

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I am having a problem with setAction in the zend form. I have a multi-page form and to all the subforms i have set the same action

```
$subForm->setAction('process')
        ->setMethod('post');
```

my forms are being rendered in index action, application controller, buyer module
http://localhost/project/public/buyer/application but when i submit the forms url is redirected/posted to url : http://localhost/project/public/buyer/process (to a page that doesnot exist)

It seems to be working when I setup a virtual server on my machine but I cannot get it to work when working with localhost or when deployed in any other server.

I tried with whole of the url but it don't seem to be working either i.e. `$subForm->setAction('buyer/applciation/process')` or `$subForm->setAction('application/process')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always found it easiest to set the form's action attribute from the view using the Url helper. Try it like this

```
<?php echo $this->form->setAction($this->url(array(
    'action' => 'process'
))) ?>
```

Comment: url is supposed to be action helper right? I am unable to use $this->url() though i am able to use it like $this->_helper->url->url(array('action'=>'process')) It seems to be working, but I have an abstract class called multipage which extends zend_form from which I am setting action to all the form while preparing the subform. I will have to make changes to few code (infact multiple places in controller in this scenario which I dont prefer) to get it work. Thank you for suggestion but I'll love to wait and see if i get better suggestion on why mine one is not working.

Comment: There are both action and view helpers named "Url". My example is from the view script but you can use the action helper in your controller if it fits your configuration better

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was wrong with my code, It seems that zend was treating my url :-
http://localhost/project/public/buyer/application as buyer controller and application action i.e. since the action is index and it is not included in my url. what my piece of code `$form->setAction('process');` would do was it would simply replace the 'application' with 'process' http://localhost/project/public/buyer/process assuming that that application was the action. If I am not wrong then that might be a bug or so it might seem.

I renamed my action index as form and now it seems to be working. Though I liked how @Phil had suggested. But just incase someone else woul

Answer (score 0):

Do you have apache setup with the rewrite rules that ZF requires?

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/project-structure.rewrite.html

Comment: Yes my rewrite rules are setup fine all of the other pages are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you did $subForm->setAction('process'), it is essentially setting a relative path to the url at /project/public/buyer/application which means it's going to assume that project, public and buyer are directories and process should be at the same level as application.

Try this:

```
$this->form->setAction('/application/process');
```

I'm not really sure what the proper url is, but I'd try using that URL with a leading / so that it's no longer relative.

Comment: Hardcoding URL strings in an MVC app is generally a bad idea. It's better to use route names or helpers (URL generators)

Comment: Absolutely agree @Phil. At this point we can only make assumptions of the setup and whether we're dealing with document root being off or whether there's a module involved. Without knowing the desired URL he wants, it's all guessing at this point anyway.

Answer (score 0):

do

```
$subForm->setAction($this->getView()->url(array('action'=>'process','controller'=>'application','module'=>'buyer'),null,true))
        ->setMethod('post');
```

Comment: it is same as what phil had suggested just that u are using view helper in controller

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me like the problem is that `process` is not an action in a controller. It looks more like a method or class being called. What you will see done most often in ZF is to set your form action to an action.

```
//set form action to a controller action where you can call process against the form.
$form->setAction('action')//or 'controller/action' or 'module/controller/action'
```

the ZF reference has a rather extensive discussion on how to do [multi part forms](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.advanced.html)

Comment: I think you didn't read the question completely and yes process is the name of my action

Comment: @Rohan Sorry I misunderstood.